# Cannot mount cgroup v1 cpu subsystem on Linux

Tags: linux, mount, cpu-usage, cgroup

Suppose on *Ubuntu 22.04*, *RHEL9* or *Centos 9 Stream* I have cgroup v2 turned off using `systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0` boot option. So I have only cgroup v1 and I want to mount `cpu` subsystem. The problem is that I can do it for `cpu,cpuacct`, `blkio`, etc. subsystems. But it does not work for `cpu` subsystem.

I get `Device or resource busy` error when mounting `cpu` subsystem. What is the problem and what is the `cpu,cpuacct`? I have searched everywhere but cannot find it.

```
# mount -t cgroup -o cpu none tmp0
mount: /root/tmp0: none already mounted on <... does not matter really ...>.
```

The output of `cat /proc/cgroups` is

```
#subsys_name    hierarchy       num_cgroups     enabled
cpuset  4       1       1
cpu     3       2       1
cpuacct 3       2       1
blkio   10      2       1
...
```

Here is the contents of `/sys/fs/cgroup`:

[image]

Here is the mounted `cgroup*` points:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/cgroups.7.html):

> It is not possible to mount the same controller against multiple
> cgroup hierarchies.  For example, it is not possible to mount
> both the cpu and cpuacct controllers against one hierarchy, and
> to mount the cpu controller alone against another hierarchy.  It
> is possible to create multiple mount with exactly the same set of
> comounted controllers.  However, in this case all that results is
> multiple mount points providing a view of the same hierarchy.\

On the systems that I've tested there was `/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct`. And AFAIU even unmounting it may be not enough if there are already some sub-folders (sub-hierarchies) inside this `/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct`, used by some processes.

In my case though it was enough to unmount `/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct` and I was able to mount with `-o cpu`, rather than with `-o cpu,cpuacct`.